# Replace date function call with its functionality

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.1

I have zero knowledge of postgresql somehow I have to extract data from a postgresql database

I am trying to replace function call in a query with its functionality.
Function:

```
-- Function: GetAppDate(bigint)  

-- DROP FUNCTION GetAppDate(bigint);  

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION GetAppDate(bigint)
  RETURNS bigint AS
$BODY$
DECLARE
    offset int := extract(timezone_hour from current_timestamp); 
BEGIN
    return ($1/10 - 62135596800000000)/1000000 + (offset * (-3600));
END;
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
  COST 100;
ALTER FUNCTION GetAppDate(bigint)
  OWNER TO postgres;
```

Query:

```
 select GetAppDate(appt.startdatetime)
  from tablename appt
```

So far i have tried, I know this is wrong :(

```
 select ($1/10 - 62135596800000000)/1000000 + ((appt.startdatetime )  * (-3600)) 
 from tablename appt
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to replace the `$1` with the column name from the select:

The query:

```
select GetAppDate(appt.startdatetime)
from tablename appt
```

passes the column `startdatetime` to the function, so your select was almost there, but no quite - you forgot to replace the `$1` and you incorrectly replaced the call to the function' variable with the column name:

```
select (startdatetime/10 - 62135596800000000)/1000000 + ((extract(timezone_hour from current_timestamp))  * (-3600)) 
from tablename appt
```

If you only have a single table in your query, then you do not need to use the table alias (the `appt`) to reference your column. If however your query contains more than one table, then you have to use the alias:

```
select (appt.startdatetime/10 - 62135596800000000)/1000000 ....
from tablename appt
  join other_table b on ...
```

Comment: I tried this timezone('UTC'::text, to_timestamp(((appt.startdatetime- 621355968000000000::bigint) / 10000000:double precision)) and worked for me am I on right track?... @a_horse_with_no_name can you please explain the difference between both of them for my understanding? Actually my requirement was to get starttime and endtime in any Standard formats instead of Bigint values.